# How can I make Tor work with an ExitNode from Portugal?

Tags: exit-relays

I live in Brazil, and I need an ExitNode from Portugal.

When I put
ExitNodes {pt} StrictNodes 1
into torrc,
it stay on "Requesting relay information".

I can use ExitNodes {us} and {br} properly.

How can I make Tor work with an ExitNode from Portugal?

Thanks

Ristor